# Want to remove children as I hitTest them but the index seem to be off

Tags: actionscript

OK, so when my lasers hit the enemies I want to remove the laser and the enemy but
my loop somehow searches outside the index and crash the program. What am I doing wrong?

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    [SWF(width = 500, height = 500, frameRate = 25, backgroundColor = 0x000000)]

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var craft:Craft = new Craft();
        private var laser:Laser;
        private var laserCollection:Vector.<Laser> = new Vector.<Laser>;
        private var laserSpeed:Number = 5;

        private var newEnemyTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
        private var enemy:Enemy;
        private var enemyCollection:Vector.<Enemy> = new Vector.<Enemy>;
        private var enemySpeed:Number = 5;

        public function Main()
        {
            addChild(craft);
            //Create a bounding box for the draggable area.
            var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(12, 460, 476, 0);
            //If you set startDrags first parameter, LockCenter to true, you don't have to explicitly set the targets position to the mouses position.
            craft.startDrag(true, rect);
            Mouse.hide();

            newEnemyTimer.start();
            newEnemyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, newEnemy);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shoot);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        }   

        private function update(e:Event):void
        {
            updateLasers();
            updateEnemies();
            checkForHit();

            trace("lasers:" + laserCollection.length + ", enemies:" + enemyCollection.length);
        }

        private function checkForHit():void
        {
            if (laserCollection.length > 0)
            {
                for (var i:int = 0; i < laserCollection.length; i++) 
                {
                    for (var j:int = 0; j < enemyCollection.length; j++) 
                    {
                        if (laserCollection[i].hitTestObject(enemyCollection[j]))
                        {
                            removeChild(laserCollection[i]);
                            laserCollection.splice(i, 1);

                            removeChild(enemyCollection[j]);
                            enemyCollection.splice(j, 1);

                            //The program crashes here because the index is outside the reach,
                            //i.e if I have 8 laser beams out and only 3 enemies, it tries to remove enemy[8]
                            // I THINK???
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function updateLasers():void
        {
            if (laserCollection.length > 0)
            {
                for (var i:int = 0; i < laserCollection.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (laserCollection[i].y > 10)
                    {
                        laserCollection[i].y -= laserSpeed;
                        laserCollection[i].alpha -= 0.01;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Can the problem be that I also remove the laser here?
                        //It seem to crash even if I hit an enemy at the bottom of the stage so shouldn't be.
                     removeChild(laserCollection[i]);
                     laserCollection.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function updateEnemies():void
        {
            if (enemyCollection.length > 0)
            {
                for (var i:int = 0; i < enemyCollection.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (enemyCollection[i].y < 500)
                    {
                        enemyCollection[i].y += enemyCollection[i].getSpeed();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enemyCollection[i].y = -20;
                        enemyCollection[i].setSpeed();
                        enemyCollection[i].x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function newEnemy(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            enemy = new Enemy();
            addChild(enemy);
            enemy.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            enemy.y = -30;
            enemyCollection.push(enemy);
        }

        private function shoot(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            laser = new Laser();
            addChild(laser);
            laserCollection.push(laser);
            laser.x = craft.x;
            laser.y = craft.y;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements of an array while iterating over it results in a problem: At the time you remove the element at `array[i]`, the following elements will move up. You still have an element at `array[i]` in the same cycle just after you removed an element. When the next loop cycle begins, `i` is incremented - and so you just skipped an element.

Two possible Solutions:

- Decrement the counter (both `i` and `j` in your case) if you have removed an element.
- Loop backwards, so the not-yet checked element's indexes won't change.

---

Another thing: Checks like `if (laserCollection.length > 0)` are not necessary here as the loops won't run anyway if the collections are empty.

Comment: What if he removes always the element at index 0?

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns If he removes `array[0]` and decrements `i`, it will be `-1`. When the loop continues, it will be incremented to `0` again, so it's always in the right range. It's ok as long as you don't use the index right after decrementing it.